# Is storing the data as json in mysql a good idea?

Tags: json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-activerecord

I got a scenario to have relational tables like a "section has many elements", so I thought of going for has_many relation model like a section has many elements.

I got some suggestions from our client saying to save the data as JSON inside a column instead of multiple tables.

I am bit confused which approach I should go with.

Suggestions are welcome.

This is the model am proposing

eg : section has_many elements

**Table : sections**

```
id  type                
1   page
```

**Table : elements**

```
id   type   content           section_id
1    text   <p>lipsum lipsum</p>     1
2    image  /images/test.png         1
```

**Client proposal is,**

```
id  type   content             
 1  page    {:text => "<p>lipsum</p>", image => "/images/test.png"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible, take a look at a record store solution like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) which will allow you to store your JSON natively. It takes some getting used to, but if JSON will be your primary storage method, this would be a wise choice.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data as a JSON in a single database field is generally a bad idea. It means you will not be able to manipulate/query the data using SQL - which kind of defeats the point of storing the data in a database.

**I'd recommend a one-to-many relationship between your `section` table and tables for `texts` and `images`. That can be achieved through [belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) and [has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) associations in Rails.**

Anyways, creating new tables will only be helpful if you have multiple texts and images for a single section. If you have a single text and a single image for each of your sections (as the example proposes), you'll probably be fine with a single `sections` table with `id`, `type`, `text`, and `image` attributes.