# Saving variable value in database and using later

Tags: mysql, node.js

json2json library converts one json format to another using a template variable.

```
    var template = {
      "path": ".",
      "as": {
        "skus": {
          "path": "students,student",
          "choose": ["name", "subject"],
          "format": function(node, value, key) {
              return { value : value };
          },
          "as": {
            "StudentName": "name",
            "StudentSubject": "subject",
          }
        }
      }
    }

    transformedJson = new json2json.ObjectTemplate( template ).transform( oldJson );
```

I want to save this template variable in database and later use it to transform json by querying database.How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your tag, you would like to insert this data into a MySQL database. You just need a client. In that case, you could use a package like [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) to do so. They provide a very basic example in their documentation (which I've very quickly and slightly adapted to your question):

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'me',
  password : 'secret',
  database : 'my_db'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('INSERT ? INTO your_table', [transformedJson], function(err, res) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(res);
});

connection.end();
```

This is, of course, assuming that you have a MySQL database, a MySQL server, etc. Generally speaking, [it's not a great idea to insert JSON into a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16977791/is-storing-the-data-as-json-in-mysql-a-good-idea) in the sense of just dumping a big object into a single field. However, MySQL 5.7.8 does support a [native JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).